# Getting the full path of a TFENode in Lion

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, finder

I'm trying to get the full path of a TFENode in OSX Lion, but am unable to get a result using the old way (by converting to an FINode and getting the fullPath - the method

```
[[FINode nodeWithFENode:myTFENode] fullPath]
```

doesn't seem to work for Lion anymore. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a TFENode, you can get an OpaqueNodeRef, and use that with FINode's nodeFromNodeRef: method. After that, you can get the NSURL to the item with FINode's previewItemURL method.

Comment: I can't find the nodeFromNodeRef: method anywhere... where can i find the header information about it?

Comment: @Orbitus007: It's not anywhere as it isn't documented. You have to generate the header information by class-dumping finder

Comment: I found the class TFENode in another repository https://github.com/infinitelabs/FinderMenu.git. You can't dump this information from the finder... someone generated a helper class called TFENode

Comment: @Orbitus007: you HAVE to get the information from Finder, either by class-dumping or by manually debugging, as this isn't in any API. The guy whose repo you linked to probably got the TFENode definitions from Finder by class-dumping it. see: http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/