# Getting full path of list view in Lion

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, finder, simbl

I have the same question that was asked in [Getting the full path of a TFENode in Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861503/getting-the-full-path-of-a-tfenode-in-lion).

I have little knowledge about Objective-c and so I am not too clear about the answer. I used [EasySIMBL](https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL) to intercept Finder process and then use [Les Nie's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294335/how-to-write-os-x-finder-plugin) to solve icon overlay in icon view, however, I cannot get the full path in list view. Can someone kindly show me how to achieve the following using Objective-C:

> From a TFENode, you can get an OpaqueNodeRef, and use that with FINode's nodeFromNodeRef: method. After that, you can get the NSURL to the item with FINode's previewItemURL method.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSClassFromString(@"FINode") nodeFromNodeRef:[(TNodeIconAndNameCell *)self node ]->fNodeRef] previewItemURL];

NSString *path = [url path];
```

Found answer here [I want to help Finder Overlay FullPath!(List Overlay)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999113)
Works for me